# How to decode / encode decimal values in python?

Tags: python, osc

I am using a network protocol to transmit OSC (open sound control messages) back and forth over a network.

The messages are received in a `byte array` as well as other formats.  I am trying to understand the byte array part of it.

An example message, in ascii is

`/track_0_volume/x "value" 0.238`

The corresponding byte array for that message is

`b'/track_0_volume/x\x00\x00\x00,sf\x00value\x00\x00\x00>s\xb6F'`

I can see looking at the byte array that there is `/track_0_volume/x` followed by three null characters, then the ascii values `sf`, a null character `value` three more null characters and then `>s\xb6F` I do not understand what the `sf` characters are nor how the `>s\xb6F` at the end represents 0.238

I believe, (I am not that familiar with OSC message formats) that the `s` indicades that the word `value` is a string type (as opposed to an `int` or `float`) and the next value is a `float` (i.e. `value` and `.238`)

The most confusing part to me is the decimal part at the end: When I try to decode that part of the byte array I get a `UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8 can't decode byte 0xb6`

I have also used `struct.unpack('f', b'\b6F')` with no success.  Anybody know how to decode that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [the documentation](http://opensoundcontrol.org/spec-1_0) a floating point number is 32 bits, big-endian.

```
>>> struct.unpack('>f', '>s\xb6F')[0]
0.23800000548362732
```

Additionally all strings end with a zero byte, plus up to 3 more zero bytes to make the length a multiple of 4. That explains all the `\x00` you have; there are 3 strings preceding the float.

P.S. My example is Python 2.7, yours appears to be Python 3. Adjust accordingly.

Comment: Brilliant Mark.  Thank you for this.  Do you mind explaining the why you need the `[0]` at the end?

Comment: @Startec, `unpack` returns a tuple but you know it will only contain one value, so it's just slicing that first value.

Comment: Last question: So, if the original byte array had two strings, (if it said `track_0_volume/x` and `extra` the byte array would instead read `b'/track_0_volume/x\x00\x00\x00,ssf...`  Can you think of a way that I could decode a varying-length set of floats, ints, or strings?  I.e., sometimes there may only be one `f` sometimes there may be two? This gets hard because it seems like there is a varying number of `null` bytes that get added depending on string length....

Comment: In my question there is a comma to separate the 'address' `track_0_volume` but there is no such thing for the following arguments.  Additionally, the varying number of nulls make it hard for me to figure out how to decode.

Comment: @Startec keep track of where within the main byte array each piece starts, and its length. If it's a string, round the length up to a multiple of 4. The way to know the length of a string is to search for the first `\x00` in it.